# UML class diagram for Xcode(Not Omnigraffle)

Tags: ios, xcode, uml, class-diagram

I finally finished my app, everything works fine and i implemented all functionalities i needed.

So now i started to make documentation. Problem is - i need UML class diagram. What's even worse - i ran out of OmniGraffle trial license. Since it's project for my studies i don't want to spend $100(which is quite a lot in my country) on software, that i might not use for a long while.

Is there any software that can generate UML class diagrams for Xcode other than OmniGraffle? For most diagrams i use lucid chart, but it seems it doesn't have UML generator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For UML try:[yUML](http://yuml.me), you can use [DFGrok](https://github.com/darkFunction/DFGrok) to generate the input to yUML from Objective-C files. For sequence diagrams [Web Sequence Diagrams](https://www.websequencediagrams.com/#).